# AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'qcut

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to bin values in dataframe column:

```
data['New_column'] = data.qcut(data['Old_column'], q=4, labels=["25%","50%","75%","100%"])
```

and getting an error:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'qcut'
```

MacOS M1, Pandas 1.4.2, Python 3.9.12, Anaconda 2022.05

Are there any solutions to this?

Comment: Are you using pandas qcut? https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.qcut.html In that case you need to use `pd.qcut`

Answer (score 0):

You must write

```py
import pandas as pd
data['new'] = pd.qcut(.....)
```